# How to retrieve PID of cmd.exe on windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, pid

How to retrieve PID of cmd.exe on windows?

I am trying to figure out PID for cmd.exe , like in Unix i can get with "ps" command what should be windows equivalent for same?

Comment: tasklist |find "cmd.exe"

will always return you list of cmd.exe with PID

if you wish to know PID of specific terminal then try :-

wmic process get parentprocessid,name|find "WMIC"
WMIC.exe                    11348

it should return the parent PID which will always be the PID of your cmd.exe

Comment: `tasklist` doesn't need `find`. Use `tasklist "imagename eq cmd.exe"`.

Comment: tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

tasklist |find "cmd.exe"

will always return you list of cmd.exe with PID

if you wish to know PID of specific terminal then execute from the terminal:-

wmic process get parentprocessid,name|find "WMIC"

WMIC.exe                    11348

it should return the parent PID which will always be the PID of your cmd.exe

Comment: Just another way: wmic process where "caption='wmic.exe'" get parentprocessid